# cordova-plugin-camera not working in IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am developing an hybrid app for Android and for IOS using ionic.

While opening the Camera from Android is working perfectly, but I am not able to open an camera from IOS device.

I install respective plugin for that

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`.

next I added the `ng-cordova.js` into `index.html` before the `cordova.js` line.

Also in `app.js` i include `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']`

In the Controller.js added `$cordovaCamera`
my code as

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,onFail, {
                      quality:90
                      destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                      sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                      allowEdit:false,
                      encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                      popoverOptions:CameraPopoverOptions,
                      saveToPhotoAlbum:true,
                      correctOrientation:true
                      })

            function onSuccess(imageURI){
                $rootScope.$broadcast("ShowAttachmentModal",imageURI);
            }
            function onSuccess(message){
                alert('Failed'+message);
            }
```

This code work perfectly in Android but not working in IOS while to open camera.

Comment: Double check to make sure the plugin is installed for iOS. I'm sure you have. But make sure before we move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MartinP, instead of ngCordova, which is being deprecated, see if you can use the replacement library Ionic-Natve (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/camera/).

Then try this code instead.

```
  function takePicture() {
      var opts = {
        quality: 90,
        encodingType: $cordovaCamera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        destinationType: $cordovaCamera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit: true,
        targetWidth: 300,
        targetHeight: 300
      };

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(opts).then(function (imageData) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("ShowAttachmentModal",imageData);;
      }, function (err) {
        $log.error(err);
      });
    }
```

The Cordova plugin is the same. You'll need to inject $cordovaCamera into your controller. Once it works, then you can play around with the options. As you may be aware, the DATA_URL option returns a Base64-encoded string. So to set it as an image's source, you'll need to prepend imageData with `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'`.